# Why do calculations provided by Skyfield not match actual data?

Tags: astronomy, skyfield

I wanted to compare the semimajor axis that Skyfield calculates with the one from TLE.

```
from skyfield.elementslib import osculating_elements_of as OE
from skyfield.api import EarthSatellite, load, utc

ts = load.timescale()

sat = EarthSatellite(TLE1, TLE2)
date = sat.epoch.utc
test = sat.at(ts.utc(*date))
print(OE(test).semi_major_axis.km)
print(sat_df['semimajor_axis_km'].values[0])
```

output:

```
7087.916048058872
7080.642
```

How come they're not the same or at least closer?

Comment: The difference that you observe is due to the fact that the TLE gives the semi major axis in ‘mean elements’ and not osculating elements!